# Understanding Python interpreter -t (-tt) option

Tags: python, python-2.7, tabs, indentation

I'm trying to figure out what the options -t and -tt do.

From the doc:

> Issue a warning when a source file mixes tabs and spaces for indentation in a way that makes it depend **on the worth of a tab expressed in spaces**. Issue an error when the option is given twice (-tt).

I'm not getting it, in particular the bolded sentence, what does it mean? A tab is a tab ('\t') a space is a space (' ') and in ascii table they also have 2 different codes.

I'll ty to make an example to explain better myself. I code:

```
if True:
    print('hello') # here a tab that my editor represents with 4 spaces
    print('world') # here just used 4 spaces
```

Now this code, I tried, doesn't work neither in Python3 nor in Python2, so what does -t do?

Could you give me a clarification?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When used as indentation, tabs must be interpreted as equivalent to a number of spaces. How *many* spaces depends on how you configured your editor, and how many spaces preceded the tab on the same line. That's because tabs represent a *jump to the next tabstop*. If you used 2 spaces plus a tab, you have signalled a jump to column 8, as if you inserted 6 spaces.

In addition, some people set their tabstops to be the equivalent of 4 spaces, others set it to be the same as 8 spaces. These people then use tabs in indentation in different ways too. You could use 4 spaces for one indentation level, then use tabs at 8 spaces for the next, then use a tab plus 4 spaces, etc. Or you could use tabs for all indentation levels, having set the tab size to represent 4 spaces.

Python needs to handle mixing of tabs and spaces, and then hope that you used it consistently; e.g. you didn't use 4 spaces first, *then* a tab to indent to what you thought was an indentation equivalent to 12 spaces. Python can easily get this wrong when you are inconsistent.

The `-t` and `-tt` options point out where you may have gotten this wrong by doing more rigorous and thorough testing of all lines.

The ease by which you can produce confusing results, between various tab sizes and mixing tabs and spaces, is the reason why the [Python Style Guide (PEP 8)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) strongly recommends that you use spaces *only*:

> Spaces are the preferred indentation method.
>
> Tabs should be used solely to remain consistent with code that is already indented with tabs.

In Python 3, *mixing* tabs and spaces for indentation is now an error.

To be precise: Python starts out assuming you used 8 spaces for a tab. See the [*Indentation* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation), part of the *Lexical Analysis* specification:

> First, tabs are replaced (from left to right) by one to eight spaces such that the total number of characters up to and including the replacement is a multiple of eight (this is intended to be the same rule as used by Unix). The total number of spaces preceding the first non-blank character then determines the line’s indentation. Indentation cannot be split over multiple physical lines using backslashes; the whitespace up to the first backslash determines the indentation.

Python 2 also looks for Emacs and VI-style configuration comments; if the tokenizer finds a comment with `tab-width:`, `:tabstop=`, `:ts=` or `set tabsize=` in it, followed by digits, like:

```
# -*- tab-width: 4 -*- (emacs)
# :tabstop=4 (vi)
```

or similar variants, then Python sets the tabsize from that. This support was removed from Python 3.

If you then mix tabs and spaces that *may* be inconsistent, and use `-t`, the text `<filename>: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation` is written to `sys.stderr` once for that file. If you used `-tt`, a [`TabError` exception](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.TabError) is raised instead.

Comment: I edited my question, because it isn't still clear to me

Comment: just to add.  actually went and tested it -t just gives you a warning while still running the code, whereas -tt does not run code and issues an error.  My advice is set your text editor to expand all tabs to spaces and you can "forget" about this as an issue

Comment: @antox: What *part* is not clear? Your sample is a syntax error in Python 3, because you are mixing tabs and spaces. In Python 2 you'll get either a warning (*inconsistent use of tabs and spaces*) or an error (a [`TabError` exception](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.TabError) is raised) depending on wether you used `-t` or `-tt`.

Comment: @antox example:   "/t"+" "*2 is sometimes equal to " "*4 but it is not totally clear.   Because python sepends on indentation to interpret the language the option just warns you if your ascii code could be misunderstood

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not understaing because either -t,-tt, or none of them I always get the same `IndentationError`, so where is the difference?

Comment: @antox: because in your example, the last line should have been indented to *8 spaces*, not 4.

Comment: Now it's pretty clear, just few questions: 1) So, in Python3 was the assumption tab=8 spaces removed? 2) If in my example I invert and I used 4 spaces and then a tab, what is the tab evaluated to?

Comment: @antox I'm out of time to verify these; the alt indent detection code is a little hard to follow. I'll update on those later.

Comment: If I can say a last thing, then what creates the problem is Python itself, because if it didn't make conversions from tabs to spaces and just considered tabs and spaces as 2 different characters all those problems there weren't.

Comment: @antox that would **not** work; tabs in your editor represent a variable amount of whitespace (jump to the next tab stop column), and Python needs to honour that.

Comment: Yes, yes, I don't mean delete the tab, I mean that if the first line of a block starts with a `\t` then the second must start with a `\t` not 8 spaces

Comment: @antox that is what Python 3 enforces and `-t` warns about.

Comment: According to your e.g.: "you didn't use 4 spaces first..." did you mean "you DID use 4 spaces first..."?

Comment: @antox: no, I misread something; Python 2 won't detect tab sizes other than the editor comments support. It is mixing tabs and spaces on the same line that is the problem; use one space plus a tab and it'll trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The error will be thrown when a source file depends on tabs expanding to a certain number of spaces.

For example, a file like this would be problematic:

```
def function():
    print 'hello'
\tprint 'goodbye'
```

The above code would work if a tab was 4 spaces, but would fail if it was anything else (except 0, which is nonsensical).

The `-t` option attempts to highlight such issues.

Comment: @antox - That's intentional.  Because it *might* not work, depending on what `\t` is set to, running python with the `-t` option will cause an error.